# Fillable pdf does not work with different devices

Tags: pdf, adobe-javascript

I have created a fillable pdf with some controls to lock fields that include two set of signature. One signature field for an instructor (Signature 1) and the other field is for a student (Signature 2).

The instructor is able to sign of the pdf form from their system. It also activates the javascript code written once the document is signed by the instructor. For one particular user, who is a student, the Signature 2 field remains disabled.

I was not able to reproduce this issue on my end and I tried using the form with Adobe Acrobat DC and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC version 2019.021.20049 on different devices (Macbook, Windows PC, Microsoft Surface Pro).

On enquiring with the student, I found out that she was using a Microsoft Surface Pro and I copied the exact same steps. We downloaded the same version, installed it, and filled up the form identical. But where I get a form with Signature 2 field enabled and ready to be used, she gets a form with Signature 2 field disabled.

Does the pdf created on adobe using javascript have any dependence on the device? This is an intermittent bug. Out of 4 students using a Microsoft Surface Pro, only 1 student is experiencing this.

Comment: Please...can anybody help with this? or even guide me to some resources?

Comment: How did you create the PDF? What library/program? Can you provide the PDF(s) in question? Are the 4 students all using the same exact application for viewing the PDF? Perhaps part of the reason you are having a hard time getting an answer is because this is a programming related stackexchange, but your are asking about Windows apps, so you might want to move this question to another stackexchange site.